# Photo recognition in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, mobile

I'm trying to develop a mobile game in unity3d, but I need some help. There will be photo recognition in the game, and I do not have clue about the topic. In pictures there will be cats with different colors, when the application see these pictures via mobile cam, a new level in game will be unlocked. I.E. the yellow cat will unlock the 5th level, and the green car will unlock the 10th level. How can I detect the pictures like these. I can't find a tutorial. If you know a good tutorial about this.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit of functionality behind what you're asking. However, one option is to look into [Vuforia](https://vuforia.com/) for implementing this. You can get a free licence for development, but you will have to [pay for it](https://developer.vuforia.com/pricing) before you launch the game.

They also offer a fair amount of [learning resources of their own](https://developer.vuforia.com/support), and they're popular enough that you should be able to find plenty of stuff elsewhere online as well.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping on @Hilse answer, the lowest level tutorial of Vuforia will tell you how to show a 3d object when the image is recognized, but you can change few params in the file VuforiaTrackableEventHandler (under Assets->Vuforia->Scripts folder) to set the active level depending on the ImageTarget recognized, maybe using a Dictionary to map ImageTarget names to scene names